# Image won't display in Internet Explorer but does in Firefox

Tags: firefox, images, internet-explorer

I'm trying to figure out why this particular image won't display in Internet Explorer 8 but I have no problem viewing it in Firefox 3.6.  The image appears to be valid and everything but Internet Explorer simply won't display it (red x placeholder image).

Any idea what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Not sure why it isn't displaying, but here is a good place to start:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283807

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been saved as CMYK rather than RGB so IE can't read it.

Other browsers and applications can, however, and the only way to tell for sure is to open it in something like Photoshop which reports the format.

Save it again as RGB format and IE will be happy.

P.S. Tell your designer to save for the web rather than print!